# geom_errorbar() overlap and positioning issues

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with geom_errorbars particularly in utilizing position_dodge() effectively in this script.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

Dose <- rep(c(3,10,30,100), each = 6)
Visit <- rep(c(1,28), each = 3, times = 4)
Animal <- rep(1:3,  times = 8)
Estimate <- runif(24)

Dose <- factor(Dose)
Visit <- factor(Visit)

df <- data.frame(Animal, Dose, Visit, Estimate)

e <- ddply(df, .(Dose, Visit), summarise, mean = mean(Estimate), sd = sd(Estimate), n = length(Estimate))
e$se = e$sd/sqrt(e$n)

trace.out <- ggplot(data = e, aes(x = Visit, y = mean, colour = Dose))
trace.out <- trace.out + 
  geom_point(data = e, aes(y = mean), size = 3, postion = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_line(data = e, aes(y = mean, group = Dose), position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= mean - se, ymax = mean + se), postion = position_dodge(0.2), colour='black', width= 0.3) +
  labs(y = 'Estimate') +
  theme_bw()

print(trace.out)
```

The output for me looks like:
[image: Wonky Lines]

I would like for the points, lines and error bars to line up and to have the errorbars not overlap. Is there some way to do that? Additionally I get an error of:

```
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
```

Would this have anything to do with it? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe facets are an option:

```
trace.out <- ggplot(data = e, aes(x = Visit, y = mean, colour = Dose, ymin= mean - se, ymax = mean + se, group = Dose))
trace.out <- trace.out + 
  geom_point(size = 3, postion = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2), ) +
  geom_errorbar(postion = position_dodge(0.2), colour='black', width= 0.3) +
  labs(y = 'Estimate') +
  theme_bw()
print(trace.out + facet_grid(~Dose) )
```

[image]

Comment: Actually that looks better than what I was expecting! thank you!